# How to call an Objects function for all instances of the object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, prototype

So I've searched far and wide across SO but wasn't able to find an answer to this (likely because I'm understanding it wrong).

I have a JS function defined like this (much simplified):

```
window.Gadget = function(name, cost){
   this.name = name;
   this.cost = cost;
   this.hasBeenRevamped = false;

   this.checkForUpdates = function(){
      console.log("checking for updates...");
   }

   window.$(window).scroll(function() {
      console.log("scrolling...");
      this.checkForUpdates(); /* The this here is erroneously referring to jQuery and not my Gadget Object. I need to fix this but am not sure how*/ 
   });
}
```

I am trying to find a way to call checkForUpdates() for all instances of Gadget, so if I have 10 Gadget objects they all check for updates when I call the function.

I ultimately want to call this function for all Gadgets whenever the window scrolls per the jQuery function $(window).scroll.

Whats the best way to achieve this? Currently, when the window scrolls, I'm seeing the console log for scrolling but then a messsage that there is no method checkForUpdates.
I believe (this) is referring to the jQuery instance and not my Gadget instance. How can I have jQuery call my Gadgets instance of checkForUpdates?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
window.Gadget = function(name, cost){
   this.name = name;
   this.cost = cost;
   this.hasBeenRevamped = false;

   this.checkForUpdates = function(){
      console.log("checking for updates...");
   }

   var self = this;

   window.$(window).scroll(function() {
      console.log("scrolling...");
      self.checkForUpdates(); /* self instead of this */ 
   });
}
```

First of all, your definition of `checkForUpdates` was wrong. You need to define it as a function for it to work.

Secondly, I added a variable named `self` in your scope, so you can refer to the actual gadget object inside the jQuery scope.

You can read more in depth about scopes [here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/).

Comment: thanks for helping! I'm curious what I would use window.gadget.prototype to set. Would this be a case where I could set a variable to a specific value for all new instances of Gadget? Would it look like this: window.Gadget.prototype.hasBeenRevamped = false;

Comment: I don't think you want to use `prototype` in this case. You would have to make an instance of Gadget like `var gadget = new window.Gadget()` then you can set the properties for the instance like this: `gadget.hasBeenRevamped = false;`. Did that answer your queation?

Answer (score 2):

It has to be a function. Like this...

```
this.checkForUpdates = function(){
    // ... Your function logic
}
```

And regarding the `this` in your jquery function, you can do this.

```
...
var thisObj = this;
window.$(window).scroll(function() {
      console.log("scrolling...");
      thisObj.checkForUpdates(); /* The this here is erroneously referring to jQuery and not my Gadget Object. I need to fix this but am not sure how*/ 
   });
...
```